# Multiple console output and one console input

Tags: java, jar

For one of my projects I need to run several jars in a single jar
Each jar returns logs to the console
Its ok but
I must be able to interact with the console user at the same time without offending the jar logs

Currently the logs are displayed well from each jar
But every time the user interacts in the chat console and click on enter the logs no longer appears

Code:
jar output

```
public ConsoleOutput(String server, InputStream is) {
    this.server = server;
    this.is = is;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            Log.print(server, line);
        }
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        Log.printError("error");
    }

}
```

and user interaction

```
    @Override
public void run() {
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        do {
            execute(br.readLine());
        } while (!interrupt);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `Log.print()`?

Comment: @RomanPuchkovskiy juste a simple System.out.print